How to add a timer to a mobile phone notification
I'm trying to get a notification in my app with a timer on it. I tried to watch some guides and get help from GPT and my Service is just not displaying my notification for some reason.
This is my service and for some reason the notification is not working. What did I do wrong and how to fix it?
package com.example.main_app;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class TimerService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "TimerService";
    public static final String TIMER_UPDATED_ACTION = "com.example.main_app.TIMER_UPDATED";
    public static final String TIMER_REMAINING_KEY = "timer_remaining";

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "TimerServiceChannel";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private long timeLeftInMillis;
    private boolean timerRunning = false;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        TimerService getService() {
            return TimerService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (timerRunning) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }

    public void startTimer(long durationInMillis) {
        if (timerRunning) {
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Timer started for: " + durationInMillis);
        timeLeftInMillis = durationInMillis;
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                Log.d(TAG, "Timer onTick: " + millisUntilFinished);
                sendTimerUpdate();
                updateNotification(millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timerRunning = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "Timer finished");
                sendTimerUpdate();
                updateNotification(0);
                stopSelf(); // Stop the service when the timer finishes
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
        timerRunning = true;
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(timeLeftInMillis));
    }

    public void pauseTimer() {
        if (timerRunning) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            timerRunning = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "Timer paused");
            sendTimerUpdate();
            updateNotification(timeLeftInMillis);
        }
    }

    public void stopTimer() {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        timerRunning = false;
        timeLeftInMillis = 0;
        Log.d(TAG, "Timer stopped");
        sendTimerUpdate();
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf(); // Stop the service when the timer is manually stopped
    }

    private void sendTimerUpdate() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TIMER_UPDATED_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(TIMER_REMAINING_KEY, timeLeftInMillis);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Timer Service Channel";
            String description = "Channel for Timer Service";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private Notification getNotification(long millisUntilFinished) {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Timer Running")
                .setContentText("Time remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " seconds")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
    }

    private void updateNotification(long millisUntilFinished) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(millisUntilFinished));
    }
}



Start here and all the following chapters: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications
In your code I don't see what android version you are targeting, this affects all the architecture of your code. Specially to get the permission to post notifications (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)
Secondarily there are very strict rules on notifications from background and foreground services (https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services). Good luck, it's a long and winding road
